Fixing the voltage leak on a soldering station - What should be done?
I found a soldering station Aixun T3A on youtube that got a very positive review.
The review said:

High temperature accuracy
Fast temperature heating speed
Low temperature overshoot
High power
Capability to calibrate
Capability to firmware upgrade

And the price sounds like a dream...but...another review said it has:

1.0V voltage leak of the tip
1.7A AC from the tip

Not sure how he could get 1.7A AC from that tip, but I can clearly said that 1.0V is 1.0V to much from that tip.
Note, many cheap soldering stations having this issue, so my question is not a unique question about the Aixun T3A series. Instead, I'm going to ask a question why this voltage leak is occurs and how to prevent them.
This Aixun T3A series have a ground connection back and if the PCB board is grounded, then fault occurs when ground is solder onto: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/reviews/aixun-t3a-misbehaving-on-grounded-pcbs/
So what can be done to achieve a 0.0 voltage leak from a tip of a soldering station?

So do you already have this soldering station? Also if you don't get any information how the voltage from soldering iron tip was measured, the measurements are useless. For example, if you have an oscilloscope and you only touch the probe tip with your finger, how many volts you get as a result, and does it mean your fingers have too much voltage so you should not touch PCBs?

@Justme I don't have this soldering station. I'm planning to buy one because I have heard good things about it. But as always, most low price soldering stations comes with an issue that it has a voltage leak onto their tips. And I wonder why does that voltage leak occurs.

@Justme And also, if the board is grounded and you soldering to that board with a soldering station that has a voltage leak, then current is going to fly though the board, which is not good at all.

@euraad without knowing the measurement technique there's no way of knowing if there even is a "voltage leak". As Justme already pointed out - touch a scope probe (or single multimeter lead) and you'll see volts ...

@brhans So there is a normal condition even if there are "voltage" if I measure with a multimeter or a scope?

Do you own a multimeter? Did you try the experiment? What did you see?

@brhans I will try out with an old Weller. Hold on.

The experiment doesn't involve a soldering station. The experiment involves testing if you yourself have a "voltage leak" - the point being that you'll get 'false positives' if your measurement technique introduces them.

@brhans I measured the voltage between the tip and the GND of my old Weller from 90's. I used a multimeter. It gave me 0.0V DC and 0.0V AC.

The T3A/B stations have the tip connected to earth ground, so if your board has some voltage relative to ground you can get current flow. A simple solution is to unplug boards before you try and solder to them, in which case no loop exists and no current will flow to ground.

@user1850479 Yes, I have heard that boards should not be grounded at all because current can flow from the tip (which is also grounded), to another ground, in this case it's the board itself. That means JBC stations has an isolated tip?

@euraad Let's step back a bit - in comments to an answer, you are worried about ESD safety, but in the question, you are worried about few volts of AC leakage. Now they are two completely different thing. You can connect the tip to earth and it will read 0VAC but is not ESD safe. You can be ESD safe and read a few volts AC. You might not be able to have both properties simultaneously.

Looks to me like the high-power tips (even the originals) are grounded and this solder station does not like having two grounds, it affects the thermocouple reading. The T12 tips, otoh, do not appear to be grounded (I could be wrong on that point). There's also some voltage drop in the cable which probably accounts for the 1V.
I don't think you can easily do much about this other than buying a $500+ JBC station instead of the knock-off if you need the high power capability to solder to ground planes and pennies.

I need a safe soldering station because I'm going to solder ESD sensitive components.

The tip is nominally grounded so ESD specifically won't be an issue (assuming the unit is plugged into a grounded outlet), but if you forget and solder something that is otherwise grounded then there could be other issues. A good name-brand solder station in that power range is not going to be especially cheap, but a good tool can serve for decades, so it's up to you.

I have an old Weller WECP-20. But it's not for fine soldering.

@euraad Why not? Get a better tip and it should be. It's 70W and temperature-controlled so it should be adequate for most jobs.

No, it's 50W and I don't know how accurate it is.

Pretty easy to check the temperature with a bead thermocouple. It's not a bad idea to do that regularly, especially if someone else is doing the soldering. Weller Germany makes some very nice solder stations too, btw. Not cheap. Some have made DIY controllers to use their cartridges, including rework tweezers.

Thank you. I will think what I should consider: Weller WECP-20 or an Aixun T3A for solder my board.

@euraad based on the datasheet for the WECP-20, temperature control should be within 2%, which is pretty reasonable. A nice fine tip e.g. T0054101799 would make it good for fine soldering.

your Weller WECP-20 is just fine for the job. You just want to ground it, and that's that. Your ESD problems with it are not based in facts, it would seem.

@TomCarpenter Yes...but....the MLR-21 handle is too long to solder. Too clumsy.

@MarcusMüller The WECP-20 might work, yes, but I'm more into JCB because I have always been using them. I love the T115 handle for JCB. And T3A can use T115 handle as well.

The handles are a factor. I have an ancient fat-handled WTCP solder station as a daily driver. So old it's 'Fabriqué au Canada' - stays put because it has a 60Hz power transformer. Electronic tools these days tend to be optimized for Asian female hands, a bit on the small side for me.

The modern soldering tools are for soldering 0201 packages

@euraad My problem with anything smaller than 0402 is between the soldering iron and chair.

Spehro.... you're damn right! I think i will give the Weller a chance!

@euraad what you can think about is getting a cheap(ish) hot air station – something that blows a bit of heat at a board can reduce a lot of rework effort to "and the I heated the thing and lifted it off the board with tweezers", and it can also help a lot if you have a component on a large plane that is especially annoying to work with because the cold copper "sucks away all the heat" – you can easily pre-heat board areas to a safe, but high temperature, before doing the actual work with the soldering iron. (Of course, esp when populating boards, a comfortable syringe + solder paste …

… molten with hot air can be nicer than soldering components with an iron – it depends. I used to do that more often in my home setting, but for complete boards, I bought a pizza oven and play "human PID controller" with a thermocouple and the power switch, and it works pretty well for things that don't need to be superb. 20 € for a small "pizza baguette oven", + 5€ for a thermocouple probe for my multimeter)

@MarcusMüller I'm planning to purchase for a hot air station and a pre heater. My goal is to solder BGA by hand and it must follow IPC class 3. So you say that I could use a pizza oven, modify it so it will work with reflow ?

never did larger BGA with it, but small BGA components definitely work – for me. But IPC class 3 entails soldering standards you wouldn't achieve with it, pretty certain.

@MarcusMüller I always solder in IPC class 3. That's why I'm hesitant to use the Weller.  I'm more used to JCB stations.

@euraad I would be kind of surprised if IPC class 3 even allowed hand soldering of BGA. This is where reflow ovens are superior.

@lundin in IPC 7075 they explain how to solder BGA. I'm planning to build my own reflow oven.
